# Oracle m5 hash returns different string than do Postgresql and bash md5sum(1)

Tags: postgresql, oracle, oracle12c, postgresql-12, md5sum

Oracle 12c:

```
SQL> select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('Tom') as hex_val, 
  2         dbms_crypto.hash(src=>UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('Tom'), typ=>2) as hex_hash
  3  from dual;
546F6D
D9FFACA46D5990EC39501BCDF22EE7A1
```

Postgresql 12.5:

```
sides=> select upper(encode('Tom', 'hex')), md5(upper(encode('Tom', 'hex')));
 upper  |               md5                
--------+----------------------------------
 546F6D | f679fe36c1c908fa2547e6915026b0af
(1 row)
```

md5sum **with** newline:

```
-bash-4.2$ echo "546F6D" | md5sum   
ef81d9f3f3e1305c92ce84efdecfd1bc  -
```

md5sum **without** newline:

```
-bash-4.2$ echo -n "546F6D" | md5sum
f679fe36c1c908fa2547e6915026b0af  -
```

As you can see, Postgres' MD5() function matches that of md5sum(1) without the newline.  That's what I expected.  However, the Oracle 12c doesn't match either, and nor does it match the md5 sum *with* newline?

What weirdness is Oracle doing (or am I making a PEBKAC mistake)?

(The ultimate purpose is to show the client that xml data successfully migrated from Oracle to Postgres.  That's why weak hashing is acceptable.)

EDIT:

Using RAWTOHEX() returns the same value as CAST_TO_RAW().

```
SQL> select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('Tom') as hex_val
  2       , dbms_crypto.hash(src=>UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('Tom'), typ=>2) as hex_hash
  3       , dbms_crypto.hash(src=>RAWTOHEX('Tom'), typ=>2) as raw_hash
  4  from dual;

HEX_VAL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HEX_HASH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RAW_HASH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
546F6D
D9FFACA46D5990EC39501BCDF22EE7A1
D9FFACA46D5990EC39501BCDF22EE7A1

SQL> select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('Tom') as hex_val
  2       , dbms_crypto.hash(src=>UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('Tom'), typ=>2) as hex_hash
  3       , dbms_crypto.hash(src=>RAWTOHEX('Tom'), typ=>2) as raw_hash
  4       , standard_hash(rawtohex('Tom'), 'MD5') as std_hash
  5  from dual;

HEX_VAL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HEX_HASH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RAW_HASH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STD_HASH
--------------------------------
546F6D
D9FFACA46D5990EC39501BCDF22EE7A1
D9FFACA46D5990EC39501BCDF22EE7A1
F679FE36C1C908FA2547E6915026B0AF
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Oracle command is hashing the hexidecimal *value*, but your Postgres and bash commands are hashing the hexadecimal *representation*. To have Oracle hash the string of the hexadecimal value, use `RAWTOHEX`:

```
SQL> select standard_hash(rawtohex('Tom'), 'MD5') from dual;

STANDARD_HASH(RAWTOHEX('TOM'),'M
--------------------------------
F679FE36C1C908FA2547E6915026B0AF
```

`DBMS_CRYPTO` and `STANDARD_HASH` work the same way, except that `DBMS_CRYPTO` only accepts the `RAW` data type.To confuse things, there is sometimes implicit conversions, and SQL*Plus may display different data types in different ways. But according to the [UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_raw.htm#ARPLS71383), "The data itself is not modified in any way, but its datatype is recast to a RAW datatype".

To compare raw values on both databases, compare `select select dbms_crypto.hash(src=>utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Tom'), typ=>2) from dual;` on Oracle with `select upper(md5('Tom'));` on Postgres - they both return D9FFACA46D5990EC39501BCDF22EE7A1.

Comment: Are you saying that `CAST_TO_RAW()` generates binary data that sqlplus is then interpreting as hex?

Comment: See my edited question.  RAWTOHEX() returns the same as CAST_TO_RAW().  Note also that I've got to use dbms_crypto.hash() because the xml data can be more than 4000 bytes.

Comment: The issue seems to be that `dbms_crypto.hash()` and `STANDARD_HASH()` do different things.

Comment: Yes, I think that SQL\*Plus is just displaying the data differently; per the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_raw.htm#ARPLS71383): "The data itself is not modified in any way, but its datatype is recast to a RAW datatype". On the Postgres side, you'll get the "D9..." value if you remove the `ENCODE` function.